# source r code, append specific value for each run. Or efficifiently pass through lapply or for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, append, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to effectively bootstrap the resultant allYears output by resampling the object A which is a list of matrices after each run of the for loop and append each run to a list. unfortunately the sample function draws randomly, and all I want to do is re-run object A sequentially before each new loop run and append the results to a list. Replicate doesn't re-run object A. Thanks in advance. See code below:

```
A <- lapply(1:4, function(x)  # construct list of matrices
  matrix(c(0, 0, 10,
           rbeta(1,5,4), 0, 0,
           0, rbeta(1,10,2), 0), nrow = 3,ncol=3, byrow = TRUE, ))

n <- c(1000,100,10)  # initial vector of abundances

nYears = 4  # define the number of years to project over

allYears <- matrix(0,nrow=3,ncol=nYears+1)  # build a storage array for all abundances

allYears[,1] <- n  # set the year 0 abundance   

i1 <- 2:ncol(allYears)

for(t in seq_along(i1)) {
  allYears[,i1[t]] <-  A[[t]] %*% allYears[,i1[t]-1]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I wrap in a function and replicate.

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(123)
Stoch_Proj_Function <- function() {A <- lapply(1:4, function(x)  # construct list of matrices
  matrix(c(0, 0, 10,
           rbeta(1,5,4), 0, 0,
           0, rbeta(1,10,2), 0), nrow = 3,ncol=3, byrow = TRUE, ))

n <- c(1000,100,10)  # initial vector of abundances

nYears = 4  # define the number of years to project over

allYears <- matrix(0,nrow=3,ncol=nYears+1)  # build a storage array for all abundances

allYears[,1] <- n  # set the year 0 abundance   

i1 <- 2:ncol(allYears)

for(t in seq_along(i1)) {
  allYears[,i1[t]] <-  A[[t]] %*% allYears[,i1[t]-1]
}

final <- allYears
}

master_array <- replicate(10,Stoch_Proj_Function())
master_list <- alply(master_array,3)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re sample and change some parameters in the A creation before each iteration, I suggest the following:

```
get_A <- function(parameter1){

  a <- lapply(1:4, function(x)  # construct list of matrices
    matrix(c(0, 0, paramter1,   # here I replace 10 with paramter10
           rbeta(1,5,4), 0, 0,
           0, rbeta(1,10,2), 0), nrow = 3,ncol=3, byrow = TRUE, ))

  return(a)

}

n <- c(1000,100,10)  # initial vector of abundances

nYears = 4  # define the number of years to project over

allYears <- matrix(0,nrow=3,ncol=nYears+1)  # build a storage array for all abundances

allYears[,1] <- n  # set the year 0 abundance   

i1 <- 2:ncol(allYears)

for(t in seq_along(i1)) {
  A <- get_A(10*t)
  allYears[,i1[t]] <-  A[[t]] %*% allYears[,i1[t]-1]
}
```

Comment: thank you that is a good approach. I am also going to posit wrapping the entire script in a function and using replicate after.